# Read data from veterinary lab unit

Tags: serial-port, usb

I have a practical question: our clients have laboratory unit which have RS232 interface. The unit have all capabilities for data transmission: baud rate, Parity, Handshake. We will use RS232 to USB converter for transmission to PC. As far as I see from unit documentation, data type is ordinary ASCII symbols. My question is - is there any way for easy reading data? I suppose that i must use some kind of terminal program or port scanner, but there is a lot of them in internet and I do not know which will be good? My question is for those who have already tried something like that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite terminal programs is Bray's.

[Bray's Terminal](https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/)

Comment: Thank you. I was also think for some kind of terminal program. I'll give it a try

Comment: Thank you. Also Termite: give us a good approach: http://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm - we made 3 tests with success - just for transfers for now...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty good option. The advantage is that this program can export data directly to Excel or a database without additional programming that can be useful in the lab environment.

http://www.aggsoft.com/asdl-rs232-to-excel.htm

Comment: Looks interesting, never saw this before